# Finding Rthevenin with respect to C1

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, thevenin, source

Howcome when I try to find Rthevenin for Part A, the resistors in the loop L1 are completely ignored? Does current not flow in L1 in this case?

Req = 60||30 ohms is the answer btw, giving us a time constant of 120uS.
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you say "Part A", what exactly do you mean? What is part A? **Please label your diagrams**. Why are you thinking resistors are ignored? When tacking these problems, don't start with the answer. Write down your steps for solving it, give us the answer *you* got by yourself and we can help correct where you went wrong

Comment: My apologies. Last line of the screenshot, it says (a) [2 marks] Calculate the time constant t1 of charging C1..... Also, i'm fine with the procedure of solving for t1, i'm just having problems with finding the thevenin resistance.

Comment: @MCG I believe "Part A" is the text that says `(a) [2 marks] Calculate the time constant....` on the very last line.

Comment: I have a hard time interpreting the circuit tbh.

Comment: The current source looks like an open circuit when you turn it down to zero.

Comment: I edited my post. That is what I see @ the left of the switch during thevenin resistance. Equivalent resistance is R1 + R2 to the left.

Comment: You need to look to the left of the switch with terminals denoted 1 and 2. C1 is the load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all perfect current sources, their effective impedance is infinite so it, and all the components to its left are redundant in the calculation of the time constant. The effective resistance seen across C1 is R5 in parallel with (R3 plus R4).

Comment: I understand that, but howcome we neglect R1 and R2? Doesn't current flow through it from the bottom of the loop?

Comment: @NirooshKa - yes, current flows in R1 and R2 but has no effect on the right side of the circuit so can be ignored. Neither does the 5V voltage source. You could remove the components and short the left side of the current source to ground with no change to the result.

Comment: Howcome it has no effect though? Doesn't that affect net current flow?

Comment: @NirooshKa No mater what 9A of current will flow through 30||(30 + 30)

Answer (score 0):

OPs Circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgZXiN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using Node1 and Node2, it should be pretty easy to understand \$i_{sc}\$ = 9 A and \$R_{th}\$ = 30 Ohms, so redrawing the equivalent circuit we have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffGRju.png)</sup>

From here you should be able to see the solution.